# JUNIT Eclipse - java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, eclipse, junit

Todos os meus testes usando JUNIT não funcionam mais.
Tentei de forma infeliz remover todos os arquivos de /bin e alguns outros de configuração .project .classpath. Ok até aqui já foi muita besteira, depois tentei criar outro projeto e passar somente as classes mas percebi que o JUNIT não funciona em nenhum projeto.

Alguém tem alguma ideia ?
[**GITHUB**](https://github.com/GADS2014M/projeto-av1-grupoA/tree/Hibernate)

**Class:**

```
package br.test;

import org.junit.Test;

public class TestMotosPersist {


    @Test
    public void criaMotos(){
        int a = 1;
    }
}
```

**Erros:**

```
TestMotosPersist [JUnit]    
    org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner at localhost:60874   
        Thread [main] (Suspended (exception ClassNotFoundException))    
            owns: Object  (id=22)   
            owns: Object  (id=23)   
            URLClassLoader$1.run() line: 366    
            URLClassLoader$1.run() line: 355    
            AccessController.doPrivileged(PrivilegedExceptionAction<T>, AccessControlContext) line: not available [native method]   
            Launcher$ExtClassLoader(URLClassLoader).findClass(String) line: 354 
            Launcher$ExtClassLoader(ClassLoader).loadClass(String, boolean) line: 425   
            Launcher$AppClassLoader(ClassLoader).loadClass(String, boolean) line: 412   
            Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(String, boolean) line: 308    
            Launcher$AppClassLoader(ClassLoader).loadClass(String) line: 358    
            LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(boolean, int, String) line: 482 
    /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/java (07/05/2015 21:58:01)
```

Isso acontece em todos os testes em qualquer projeto, já tentei remontar projeto, reiniciar o eclipse..etc

Quem quiser ver o source completo
[**GITHUB**](https://github.com/GADS2014M/projeto-av1-grupoA/tree/Hibernate)

[image: Arquivos]
[image: Erros]

Comment: Tente colocar o jar do junit dentro da pasta libs.

Comment: Obrigado pela atenção amigo, Não consegui uma solução direta para o problema, precisei deletar .metadata em workspace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver, não foi a melhor solução mais consegui.

A bagunça que fiz com eclipse estava no arquivo .metadata que fica oculto na pasta workspace (caso você use a pasta default).

Para visualizar o arquivo Aperte ctrl + H no ubuntu e no windows tem a opção de mostrar ocultos na configuração de pastas
[image: Diretórios do sistema]

Removendo a pasta, o Eclipse reconfigurou tudo e voltou a funciona. Esse problema não era bem sobre Java, e sim configuração do eclipse. Por isso desculpe, sei que isso foge o escopo do SO, mas eu não sabia.